# predicting gender of a person based on census in R

Tags: r

I have three data frames, one which has customer's name , second which has female names and third with male names. If a customer's name is present in male names df then it is assigned gender as male and similarly for female. But in case a name is present in both male and female data frames then I have to use the count to assign the gender.

For e.g.

```
male_names <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Ajit","Binod","Chinmay","Dhiraj","Eshan","Krishna"),  
  count = c(4,2,3,4,2,7)
)

female_names <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Amita","Binita","Cherry","Deepika","Krishna"), 
  count = c(4,1,2,3,2)
)

customer_names <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Ajit","Binita","Dhiraj","Krishna")
)
```

How should i do it ?

Comment: Seems like case_when in the dplyr package could be a good fit. see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach with `dplyr`:

```
female_names %>%
  full_join(male_names, by = "Name") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(Name, gender = ifelse(count.x > count.y, "female", "male"), .keep = "none") %>%
  right_join(customer_names, by = "Name")
```

Results:

```
     Name gender
1  Binita female
2 Krishna   male
3    Ajit   male
4  Dhiraj   male
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to first merge your female and male names and take a sum, so you know what gender you want to assign for each name. Then join your customers to that table. I use data.table here, just my preference.

```
library(data.table)

gender_by_name <- setDT(merge(male_names, female_names, by = "Name", all = T))[, .(gender = ifelse(sum(count.x, -count.y, na.rm = T) > 0, "male", "female")), Name]
gender_by_name[setDT(customer_names), on = .(Name)]
```

**results**

```
Name gender
1:    Ajit   male
2:  Binita female
3:  Dhiraj   male
4: Krishna   male
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the gender with the highest number across genders.

[Edit: realised this will keep both sexes in the case the numbers are equal, but the question isn't clear about what should happen in that case]

```
bind_rows(male=male_names, female=female_names, .id = "gender") |> 
       group_by(Name) |>
       filter(count==max(count)) |>
       merge(customer_names)

     Name gender count
1    Ajit   male     4
2  Binita female     1
3  Dhiraj   male     4
4 Krishna   male     7
```

But I would think carefully about what you are going to do with this data and whether this is an appropriate way to guess gender.